# If two consecutive numbers are removed from the series $1+2+3+\ldots+n$ the average becomes $99/4$. Find the two numbers.

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic, average

The initial average will be $\frac{n+1}{2}$. If the two numbers are $k$ and $k+1$ then the new average will be $\frac{n(n+1)/2-(2k+1)}{n-2}$. I couldn't figure further even though I got the relation between $n$ and $k$ in many different ways.

If the question is not clear, here is an example to explain it.
If $n=10$, the initial average will be $5\cdot 5$ {$(1+2+\cdots + 10)/10$}
Now if two consecutive numbers like $2,3$ or $8,9$ are removed from this series, the new average changes, and this new average has been given to be $99/4$, however we also don't know the value of $n$, so the question seems to be pretty difficult.

Comment: The initial average is $(n+1)/2$, not $(n+1)/n$.

Comment: That's what I wrote on paper, but I made a typo in the question. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: How can this sequence be said to have an average? For any given average, there exists an $n$ such that the average of $n$ or more terms is greater than the given one.

Comment: What about the the average of _1+2+3+...10?_ It is 5.5. And if we remove two consecutive terms for example 2,3 the average changes. This is what the question is saying. Just we don't know the number of terms, and we have to also find the two consecutive numbers which have been removed. Hope that makes it clear.

Comment: In that case, please edit your question to clarify that we are trying to solve for $n$ as well (also saying what $n$ is).

Comment: I don't know if we **need** to solve for n. Maybe someone can directly get the numbers without finding n. So I leave it up to you to find _n_ or not.

Comment: $\frac{n(n+1)/2-(2k\color{red}+1)}{n-2}$.  Interesting question!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As in Claude Leibovici's answer, removing $k+(k+1)$ from $1+2+\cdots+n$ to leave an average of $99/4$ implies, after a bit of algebra, that

$$k={2n^2-97n+194\over8}$$

is an integer between $1$ and $n-1$.  It's easy to see that $k$ being an integer implies $n\equiv2$ mod $8$.  If we write $n=8m+2$ (with $m\gt0$, since $n=2$ is obviously not possible), we find, after a tad more algebra, that $k=16m^2-89m+1$.  The inequality constraints are thus now

$$1\le16m^2-89m+1\le8m+1$$

or

$$89\le16m\le97$$

There is clearly only one integer solution:  $m=6$, corresponding to $n=50$ and $k=43$.

Comment: This problem is really amazing. Manipulating inequalities, the bounds are so close to each other !

Answer (score 7):

The new average will be $$\frac{\frac{n(n+1)}2-(2k+1)}{n-2}=\frac {99}4$$ Solving for $k$ gives $$k=\frac{2 n^2-97 n+194}{8} $$ which must be a positive integer lower or equal to $n$.

Solving for $n$ gives $$n=
\frac{97+\sqrt{64 k+7857}}{4} $$ which must be an integer.

Now consider the extreme cases $k=1$ and $k=n-1$; this gives very narrow bounds for $n$. From algebra, $k=1\to n=\frac{93}2$ and $k=n-1\to n=\frac{101}2$.  In the worst case, only four values of $n$ would need to be tested.

Does this help you ?

Comment: I guess not. My teacher asked for the values.

Comment: @HarshaG.. There is a solution. Try to find it.

Comment: I did get this relation myself, but it doesn't lead to much revelation.

Comment: Actually, $k+1 \le n$.

Comment: @lhf. You are right !

Comment: @HarshaG. If $n$ is large \frac{n+1} 2\approx \frac {99}4$. This really limts the possibilities.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici But how can we get those integer values? How can we find them.

Comment: Another way is doing $k = ((n-2)(2n-97)+4n)/8$ from which an argument can be made that $n = 8m + 2$ for some $m$ (these produce integers). The first root of $2n^2 - 97 + 194$ can be found, and $n$ taken as the smallest value of the form $8m + 2$ which is greater than this root.

Comment: $k=1$ and $k=n-1$ yields $n=2$, which makes the initial expression illegal (division by $0$).

Comment: Can anybody tell

Comment: How to delete a comment? I am new to this website. Also, isn't there a better way to get the answer, rather than plugging in extremities, and then trying to figure it out?

Comment: Next to your comment, there are two buttons **edit** and **delete**

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Oddly enough, I don't see any such buttons, maybe because I'm on mobile. Thanks for your solution by the way.

Answer (score 4):

This approach finds that the new average lies within $\pm 1$ of the original average. This significantly narrows down possibilities, and the solution can then be found easily by elimination.

---

After removing the two numbers, the new average, $a$, is given by
$$\begin{align}
\frac {99}4=a&=\frac{\frac{n(n+1)}2-(2k+1)}{n-2}\\
&=\underbrace{\frac {n+1}2}_{\text{original average, $a_0$}}+
\underbrace{\frac {n-2k}{n-2}}_{\in [-1,1] \text{ for } 1\le k\le n-1}
\end{align}$$

Hence $a$ lies within $\pm 1$ of the original average $a_0$ before removal, i.e.
$$a_0-1\;\le\; a=\frac {99}4=24.75\;\le\; a_0+1$$

As $a_0=\frac {n+1}2$, it can only be either an integer or an integer and a half, hence
$24\le a_0\le 25.5$.

$$\begin{array} {lrrrr}
\hline{a_0(n)=\frac{n+1}2} &24&24.5&25&25.5\\
n  &47 &48 &49 &\color{red}{50}\\
n-2  &45 &46 &47 &\boxed{48} \\
a-a_0(n)=\frac {n-2k}{n-2}&\frac 34&\frac 14&-\frac14&-\frac34\\
\hline
\end{array}$$
Also, the sum of the remaining numbers $\frac {99}4 (n-2)$ must be integer, so $(n-2)$ must a multiple of $4$, the only candidate for which is $48$.

Hence we conclude that $\color{red}{n=50, k=43}\qquad \blacksquare$

Answer (score 2):

We have, that the sum of $n+1$ terms, excluding the $m$-th and $m+1$-th, is:
$$
\begin{gathered}
  S(n + 1,m) = \sum\limits_{1\, \leqslant \,k\, \leqslant \,m - 1} k  + \sum\limits_{m + 2\, \leqslant \,k\, \leqslant \,n + 1} k  = \sum\limits_{1\, \leqslant \,k\, \leqslant \,m - 1} k  + \sum\limits_{1\, \leqslant \,k\, \leqslant \,n - m} {\left( {k + m + 1} \right)}  =  \hfill \\
   = \left( \begin{gathered}
  m \\ 
  2 \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right) + \left( {m + 1} \right)\left( {n - m} \right) + \left( \begin{gathered}
  n + 1 - m \\ 
  2 \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right) =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}
{2}m\left( {m - 1} \right) + \left( {m + 1} \right)\left( {n - m} \right) + \frac{1}
{2}\left( {n + 1 - m} \right)\left( {n - m} \right) =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}
{2}\left( {m\left( {n - 1} \right) + \left( {n + 3} \right)\left( {n - m} \right)} \right) =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}
{2}\left( {n\left( {n - 1} \right) + 4\left( {n - m} \right)} \right) = \frac{{n\left( {n + 3} \right)}}
{2} - 2m \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
So we shall have:
$$
\begin{gathered}
  \frac{{S(n + 1,m)}}
{{n - 1}} = \frac{{99}}
{4}\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \begin{gathered}
  n - 1 = 4\,q \hfill \\
  S(n + 1,m) = \frac{{n\left( {n + 3} \right)}}
{2} - 2m = 99\;q \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow  \hfill \\
   \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \begin{gathered}
  1 \leqslant m \leqslant n = 4\,q + 1 \hfill \\
  n\left( {n + 3} \right) = 198\;q + 4m \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right. \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
The last gives:
$$
\begin{gathered}
  4 \leqslant 4\left( {4q + 1} \right)\left( {q + 1} \right) - 198\;q = 4m \leqslant 4\left( {4\,q + 1} \right) \hfill \\
  0 \leqslant \left( {4q + 1} \right)\left( {q + 1} \right) - \frac{{198}}
{4}\;q - 1 \leqslant 4\,q \hfill \\
  0 \leqslant q^{\,2}  - \frac{{178}}
{{16}}\;q \leqslant \,q \hfill \\
  0 \leqslant q - \frac{{178}}
{{16}} \leqslant \,1 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
i.e.
$$
\frac{{178}}
{{16}} \leqslant q \leqslant \,\frac{{194}}
{{16}}\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \left\lceil {\frac{{178}}
{{16}}} \right\rceil  \leqslant q \leqslant \,\left\lfloor {10 + \frac{{34}}
{{16}}} \right\rfloor \quad  \Rightarrow \quad 12 \leqslant q \leqslant 12
$$
In conclusion, so we have:
$$
\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  q = 12 \hfill \\
  n = 4\,q + 1 = 49 \hfill \\
  m = \frac{1}
{4}\left( {n\left( {n + 3} \right) - 198\;q} \right) = 43 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.
$$
which in fact gives:
$$
\frac{{S(n + 1,m)}}
{{n - 1}} = \frac{{\frac{{n\left( {n + 3} \right)}}
{2} - 2m}}
{{n - 1}} = \frac{{\frac{{49 \cdot 52}}
{2} - 86}}
{{48}} = \frac{{1188}}
{{48}} = \frac{{99}}
{4}
$$

Comment: This solutions seems really intriguing, but in a good way. I am in High School, maybe that is why. Which topic in Maths is this solution part of?

Comment: This is nice, for sure.

Comment: @HarshaG., well actually there is no much of sophisticate about. In the first line I splitted the sum substantially into three parts, but you can easily do it if just you know how to compute $ \sum\limits_{a\, \leqslant \,k\, \leqslant \,b} k$ which is just $n.\, of\, terms \times avg.\, value = n.\, of\, terms \times (1st\, term+last\, term)/2$. Then the rest is just manipulation of inequalities, and final is just to find the integer value of $q$ respecting the bounds.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, glad of appreciation!

Comment: When things are good, why not to tell they are ? I am always impressed by people able to do arithmetic stuff. Cheers and thanks again for your answer. Amazing problem, isn't it ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, it is nice to know  a fair guy! the problem is really intriguing and compliments go to whom has invented it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a calculated guessing approach. The average of $ n $consecutive integers will be. $ (n+1)/2$. $99/4$ is a little less than$ 25$. So $n $can be taken to be$ 50$. Not$ 49,$ because two less than$ 49$, which is $47 $is not divisible by $4$. So first$ 50 $numbers sum will be$ 1275$. $99/4 * 48$ will be$ 1188.$ Here $48 $is divisible by $4$ is the reason I took $ n=50. $.  $ 1275-1188$ will be$ 87$. two consecutive numbers giving $87$ as sum are$ 43,44$. I hope this is of some help